# My Java getting a little complex

Tags: java

```
public interface Interface1<E extends Interface1<E,F>,F extends Interface2<E,F>>{
    public Q<E,F> do();
}

public interface Interface1<E extends Interface1<E,F>,F extends Interface2<E,F>>{
    public doTo(Q<E,F> arg);
}
```

is this ok because me is using interface name in the generic part within the same interface, like E extends Interface1... being called in Interface1.

Is this ok?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "OK"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is 'okay' to do, but you should probably complete the generic type for Interface1 and Interface2

```
public class Q<E extends Interface1<E, F>, F extends Interface2<E, F>>{
    E interface1;
    F interface2;
}
```